# How to remove duplicates ArrayList from an ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, integer, set

Problem: Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in S such that a + b + c = 0?
Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

My Code:

```
public class Solution {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> threeSum(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> C = new  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        int n = A.size();
        for(int i =0; i<n-2; i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<n-1; j++){
                for(int k=j+1; k< n; k++){
                    int sum = A.get(i)+A.get(j)+A.get(k);
                    if(sum == 0){
                        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        temp.add(A.get(i));
                        temp.add(A.get(j));
                        temp.add(A.get(k));
                        C.add(temp);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
      return C;
    }
}
```

So **C** may contains repeated Arraylist, and my aim is to remove repeated Arraylist from C

Example: C = [-5 1 4 ] [-5 1 4 ] [-5 1 4 ] [-5 4 1 ] [-4 0 4 ] [-4 0 4 ]
My aim to get = [-5 1 4 ] [-5 4 1 ] [-4 0 4 ]

Please suggest me some ways to do some operation on C so that I can do it.

Comment: Try to use formatting your code in your question to get better answers. Repeating the language `Java` somewhere in your text might help as well. So far it is only present in the tags...

Answer (score 1):

The equals method of AbstractList (which ArrayList extends) is defined so that two lists are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. The simplest way then would be to get the distinct lists from a stream:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Arrays.asList(-5, 1, 4));
list.add(Arrays.asList(-5, 1, 4));
list.add(Arrays.asList(-5, 4, 1));
list.add(Arrays.asList(-4, 0, 4));
list.add(Arrays.asList(-4, 0, 4));
list.add(Arrays.asList(-4, 0, 4));

List<List<Integer>> distinctLists = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(distinctLists); // prints [[-5, 1, 4], [-5, 4, 1], [-4, 0, 4]]
```